NestJS/Automapper - Error while mapping a Prisma Type object using Pojos strategy
Using NestJS with Prisma for a Postgre backend DB. Trying to use Automapper as a part of that, but getting error when starting

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TestProfile (?). Please
make sure that the argument "automapper:nestjs:default" at index [0]
is available in the TestModule context.

Below is the code:
app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AutomapperModule } from '@automapper/nestjs';
import { pojos } from '@automapper/pojos';
import { TestModule } from './test/test.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    AutomapperModule.forRoot(
      [
          {
              name: 'pojos',
              strategyInitializer: pojos(),
          },
      ],
  ),
    TestModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}

test.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TestController } from './test.controller';
import { TestService } from './test.service';
import { PrismaService } from 'prisma/prisma.service';
import { TestProfile } from 'src/automapper/test.profile';
import { AutomapperModule } from '@automapper/nestjs';
import { pojos } from '@automapper/pojos';

@Module({
  imports: []
  controllers: [TestController],
  providers: [PrismaService, TestProfile, TestService],
  exports: [TestService],
})
export class TestModule {}

test.profile.ts
import { AutomapperProfile, InjectMapper } from '@automapper/nestjs';
import { createMap, type Mapper } from '@automapper/core';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TestDto } from './Test.dto';
import { Test } from '@prisma/client';
import { PojosMetadataMap } from "@automapper/pojos";

@Injectable()
export class TestProfile extends AutomapperProfile {
    constructor(@InjectMapper() mapper: Mapper) {
        super(mapper);

        createTestMetadata();
    }

function createTestMetadata() {
    PojosMetadataMap.create<Test>('Test', {
        id: String,
        description: String
    });

    PojosMetadataMap.create<TestDto>('TestDto', {
        id: String,
        description: String,
        comment: String
    });
}

    override get profile() {
        return (mapper: Mapper) => {
            createMap<Test, TestDto>(
                mapper,
                'Test', 
                'TestDto', 
            );
        };
    }
}

Test Dto object is defined as
export class TestDto {
    id: number;
    description?: string;
    comment: string;
}

Original Test Type is defined in Prisma model
This whole gives the error as mentioend in the beginning. If I remove the TestProfile in the providers for TestModule, then all works fine, but AutoMapper won't work.
What is going wrong here?
